# Why will the result print [1 255 0] not [0 255 0] instead?

Tags: image, numpy, jpeg

I am changing RGB values. Why will the result print [1 255 0] not [0 255 0] instead?

```
pic = cv2.imread("eat.jpg")

for x in range(pic.shape[0]):
    for y in range(pic.shape[1]):
        pic[x, y, 0] = np.array(0)
        pic[x, y, 1] = np.array(255)
        pic[x, y, 2] = np.array(0)

cv2.imwrite('change.jpg', pic)

pic = cv2.imread("change.jpg")
print(pic[0, 0])
```

Comment: I can reproduce this. Odd. Investigating...

Comment: It will be fine if I change the change.jpg to the change.bmp.

Comment: Perhaps it's something to do with JPGs particular.

Comment: [JPEG is lossy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression).  To rely on the preservation of values, use a lossless format, such as PNG.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the exact cause, but I suspect it has to do with value overflow (because the dtypes are `unit8`), because if you change the middle value to `254` then write and re-read the image, it wil come out as `[0 254 0]`, not `[1 254 0]`. Also, if you write `[0 0 255]`, you'll get back `[0 0 254]`